# Offline caching is not loading updated files

Tags: html, offline, offline-caching

I have created a web app that can be accessed offline. However the problem I am having is getting the browser to display the new version of the page.

I can see that the files are being downloaded again:

```
Application Cache Downloading event
Application Cache Progress event (0 of 3) pad/jquery.min.js
Application Cache Progress event (1 of 3) pad/index.html
Application Cache Progress event (2 of 3) pad/
Application Cache Progress event (3 of 3) 
Application Cache UpdateReady event
```

However upon a refresh of the page, the old index.html file is still being displayed.

I have set up my offline.manifest file properly and referenced it in the html tag. I am not sure what could be the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you may have to manually swap the new cache in using javascript. Here's what I have on my pages to deal with the issue:

```
<script>window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {window.applicationCache.swapCache();window.location.reload();} else {}}, false);}, false);</script>
```

This will automatically swap in the new cache and reload the page when it's available. You can [get more info on using javascript with appcache here at html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/#toc-updating-cache)